# ¿Cómo ejecutar cron con script?

Tags: bash, cron

Estoy intentado programar algunas tareas muy sencillas, pero no consigo que se ejecute ninguna. El uso es con **cron**.

Una de las tareas es que se abra la calculadora o bien un navegador web.

En el cron tengo lo siguiente, pero no se ejecuta con ningún usuario:

```
30 17 * * * bc
```

Otra de las tareas es mostrar un mensaje por pantalla. Para ello creo un mini script con lo siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
notify-send 'Hola''Como va todo?'
```

El script tiene permisos de ejecución, así que ya no sé si es problema de **cron** o lo estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El usuario que lanza cron tiene un entorno muy limitado: su variable `$PATH` contiene muy pocos directorios y eso le imposibilita encontrar la mayoría de comandos que usualmente llamarías con su nombre directamente.

Esto puedes verlo creando un script sencillo:

```
echo "$PATH" >> /tmp/bla
```

En mi caso apenas devuelve dos rutas: `/usr/bin:/bin`.

Entonces, si `notify-send` no se encuentra en ninguno de los directorios que tiene `$PATH` al ejecutar el cron, debes indicarle dónde está exactamente. Esta información la puedes obtener escribiendo `which notify-send`. En mi caso está en `/usr/bin/notify-send`, por lo que no sería necesario poner toda la ruta, pero igualmente **es buena práctica poner la ruta completa de todos los binarios que ejecutas en un archivo de cron**.
Por ello, debes indicarle explícitamente dónde están los comandos pues su `PATH` no tiene tanto como querríamos.

Además, para que notify-send funcione en un cron, debes tener la variable de entorno `DISPLAY` definida como ":0". Es decir, debes añadir esta línae al principio de tu script: `export DISPLAY=:0`.

Por tanto, tu script pasaría a ser:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
/usr/bin/notify-send 'Hola, ¿cómo va todo?'
```

---

En cuanto al script que lanza `bc`, no tiene sentido hacerlo: cuando en la consola escribes `bc`, este programa se abre en la consola en que estás trabajando. Cuando lo haces en un script de cron, simplemente lo hará en un lugar en el que no tienes acceso, por lo que no tendrás forma de usarlo.

Answer (score 0):

### Cronificando la tarea con cron

> Para añadir el script a la lista de programas a ejecutar
>   periódicamente por cron    podemos usar la orden crontab -e, que abre
>   con el editor predeterminado el archivo de las tareas cronificadas de
>   nuestro usuario en el sistema.

Para que el script se ejecute con una periodicidad mensual, añadiremos una línea como la siguiente:

```
0 0 1 * * /home/usuario/bin/ejemplo.sh
```

> La sintaxis de crontab es fácil e intuitiva. El último parámetro de la
>   línea es la ruta al script, absoluta si no está en una carpeta dentro
>   de PATH.
>
> El archivo que contiene el script debe tener permisos de ejecución. Como contendrá toda la información necesaria para acceder a
>   nuestra base de datos es conveniente darle permisos 700:

```
$ chmod 700 ejemplo.sh
```